# Error importing request processor module Django

Tags: python, django

While trying to configure the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT PROCESSORS in Django settings.py I am getting the following error:

```
        Exception Value: Error importing request processor module  
        django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messagesdjango.core.context_processors: 
        "No module named 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messagesdjango'; 
        django.contrib.messages.context_processors is not a package"
```

My TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS is as follows: (Django Version: 1.5.1)

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
  "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
  "django.core.context_processors.debug",
  "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
  "django.core.context_processors.media",
  "django.core.context_processors.static",
  "django.core.context_processors.tz",
  "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages"
  "django.core.context_processors.request",
)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're missing a comma after your inclusion of `messages`, between these two lines:

```
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages"
"django.core.context_processors.request",
```

Should be:

```
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
"django.core.context_processors.request",
```

Comment: Every programmer has been there before.

Comment: It's the worst sort of error because it makes you feel dumb even if you aren't. Cheer up and carry on.